# How do I print lines in awk where one column matches a value?

Tags: linux, awk

So I have a large file with a few million lines of comma-separated values.

```
132.3,-23.3,1659614391.4174244,539.0,0,l_top
132.3,-23.1,1659614391.4174244,548.0,0,l_top
131.9,-22.900000000000002,1659614391.4174244,539.0,0,l_top
132.1,-22.700000000000003,1659614391.4174244,541.0,0,l_top
132.20000000000002,-22.5,1659614391.4174244,548.0,0,l_top
131.8,-22.200000000000003,1659614391.4174244,543.0,0,l_top
133.5,-22.3,1659614391.4174244,551.0,0,l_top
133.0,-22.1,1659614391.4174244,547.0,0,l_top
133.5,-21.900000000000002,1659614391.4174244,545.0,0,l_top
133.5,-21.700000000000003,1659614391.4174244,558.0,0,l_top
…
```

I try to extract lines where the last column has value `l_top` with awk like this

```
awk -F ',' '{ if ($6 == "l_top") { print } else { exit }}' <file>
```

which prints nothing. It works fine if I filter on another column, e.g. `$5 == 0`. Maybe line endings are somehow at fault?
What is the correct way to filter based on column value?

Answer (score 2):

This is because `exit` means "exit the program", so your program will exit on the first line that doesn't end with `l_top`. You were probably looking for `next`:

```
awk -F ',' '{ if ($6 == "l_top") { print } else { next }}' <file>
```

However, the default action in awk when something evaluates to true is to print the line, so you don't even need an explicit `print`. All you need is:

```
awk -F, '$6 == "l_top"' file
```

Or just:

```
grep ',l_top$' file
```

Comment: yes, i accidentally posted the wrong command, i terminate with exit intentionally.
however the program terminated without output even though the first couple lines have the matching pattern.

Comment: What I originally ran was this `awk -F ',' '{ if (NR <= 10000 && $6 == "l_top") { print $9 } else { exit }}`. Most of the initial lines have the `l_top` pattern in `$6`, but still no output.

Comment: What works for me is this `awk -F, '{ if ($6 ~ /l_top/) { print $1,$2,$3,$4 } }'` if i omit the requirement to output only the first n lines.

Comment: @oarfish  "What works for me"? (a) using `~` to match a fixed text is slow (and you have "a few million lines"), and it would also match `anything l_top junk`. (b) Your output will be space-separated, no longer CSV. (c) It is not idiomatic -- awk has the pattern/action style so the `if` is redundant. `'$6 == "l_top" { print $1,$2,$3,$4 }'`

Answer (score 2):

[terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/722181/116858) is a solution to your question, and it also describes why your code terminates at the first record that does not fulfil the filter criteria (in short: `exit` terminates the run).  However, if you have a CSV file with more complicated fields (with literal commas and newlines etc.), you will need to use a CSV-aware tool to extract the records you're looking for.

Here's using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to parse the header-less CSV file `file.csv`, and extract the records whose last field is the string `l_top`:

```bash
mlr --csv -N filter '$[NF] == "l_top"' file.csv
```

or, to access the 6th column by number,

```bash
mlr --csv -N filter '$6 == "l_top"' file.csv
```

or, if you have headers, and the header for the last field is `label` (not the dropped `-N` here):

```bash
mlr --csv filter '$label == "l_top"' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You have DOS line endings so `$6` isn't `l_top`,  it's `l_top\r`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it.

Change your command to:

```
awk -F ',' '{ sub(/\r$/,""); if ($6 == "l_top") { print } else { exit }}' <file>
```

Comment: I actually tried that to no avail.

Comment: We can't help you debug `to no avail`. If you want help debugging a problem then you have to provide symptoms of the problem.